# Is this true or false about indexing

Tags: mysql

Indexing will fasten the INSERT and UPDATE commands
and will slow down the search operation.
a. True
b. False

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**b. False**, it's actually the opposite. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) says (emphasis mine):

> A database index is a data structure that **improves the speed of data retrieval operations** on a database table **at the cost of additional writes** and storage space to maintain the index data structure.

Writing (INSERT & UPDATE) will take more time, because you might have to update the index as well. Search (SELECT) is data retrieval and an appropriately chosen index will improve the performance of a particular search query.

Actually, in the case of [foreign keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key), an index on the referenced field(s) in the parent table can speed up insert and update operations in the child table. And it's possible to slow down a search query by forcing or tricking the query optimizer to use a certain suboptimal index. But I guess neither was intended when the question was asked.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you are talking about a SQL DB. An index is a lookup table for row data. As a result, updates that change the data the index is based on will be slightly slower as it has to update both the row data and the index data. However, correctly chosen indexes will result in SELECTs of data being MUCH faster. With larger tables it can be several magnitudes faster. Without indexes, SELECT statements will have to scan every row in your table.